# Magic property method

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component, getter-setter

I'm trying to create a component that will handle the configuration of our app. Since I don't know beforehand what attributes might get set I map them manually to a `settings` object on my component. I'd like to create a magic function so whenever I try to get a property the component will get the property from the `settings` object.

### What I've tried

I figured that I'd need to use [a proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy#Basic_example) but I can't figure out how to get it to work in a component. Do I add it in the `ready` lifecycle callback?

Comment: *"I'd like to create a magic function so whenever I try to get a property the component will...."* When you try to get a property *from what*?

Comment: The component I'm creating

Comment: So when code anywhere does `component.foo`, you want the magic function to kick in?

Comment: That's exactly my plan =)

Answer (score 0):

The naïve implementation below uses nested [`app-storage`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-storage) App Element to simplify the persistence of settings between sessions. There is no need in proxy in such a case. [The code is not tested, since I don’t have an environment to test in right now, but it’s pretty straightforward and should work out of the box.]

```
<dom-module id="my-config">
  <template>
    <app-localstorage-document key="settings"
                               data="{{settings}}">
    </app-localstorage-document>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "my-config",

      properties: {
        settings: {
          type: Object,
          value: false,
          // notify: true,                 // use this to stay tuned
          // observer: '_settingsChanged'  // use this to stay tuned
        }
      },

      created: function() {
        console.log('Settings created and loaded: [', settings, ']!');
      },

      get: function(key) {
        return this.settings[key];
      },

      set: function(key, value) {
        return this.settings[key] = value;
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

---

Using “magic properties”:

```
  properties: {
    settings: {
      type: Object,
      value: new Proxy({}, {
        get: function(target, key) {
          return key in target? target[key] : nil;
        },
        set: function(target, key, value) {
          return target[key] = value;
        }
      })
    }
  },
```

Comment: I know using a function (get) works, but I was wondering if there was a way to use magic properties

Comment: Please see update. `settings.foo` should now work as expected. I am nevertheless sure that `get/set` approach is waaaay more clean.

Comment: Hm, unexpected token: proxy

Comment: I really can't think of a way how to, sorry

Comment: Oh, there was s stupid typo in my example, of course there must be a valid object, e.g. `value: new Proxy({}, {` rather than `new Proxy({}, {` as it was before.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks! I'll try to get it to work soon =) here's the element if you'd like to take it for a spin: https://github.com/jordyvandomselaar/jvd-config